# iOS swift: UICollectionview horizontal scroll single cell not reloading

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

In my application UICollection scroll horizontally. collection-view cell two button and one UIView was designed.

Each cell loaded two button. when user click one button the particular cell should be reload and the UIView will be displayed in that cell only other cell not displayed.

Here i attached the collectionview image:
[image]

Here my code:

```
     @IBOutlet weak var dataCollectionView: UICollectionView!
        var addIndexArray:[Int] = []
        var arraySelectedFilterIndex = [IndexPath]()
        
        self.listArr = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t"]
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
             self.dataCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return (lvsnListArr.count/2)
        }
    
          func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                
                let cell = dataCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier_CollectionView, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! DataCell
        
                if self.arraySelectedFilterIndex.contains(indexPath) {
        
                    cell.buttonView.isHidden = false
        
                }else{
                   cell.buttonView.isHidden = true
                }
                
                cell.btn1.setTitle(lvsnListArr[2 * indexPath.row], for: .normal)
                cell.btn1.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.btn1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
                cell.btn2.setTitle(lvsnListArr[2 * indexPath.row + 1], for: .normal)
                cell.btn2.tag = indexPath.row
                cell.btn2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btn2Pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
                return cell
            }
    
        @objc func btnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
            
            self.addIndexArray.append(sender.tag)
            
            let hitPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: dataCollectionView)
            if let indexPath = dataCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: hitPoint) {
                print("indexPath--->",indexPath)
                self.arraySelectedFilterIndex.append(getIndexPath)
                self.dataCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [getIndexPath])
                
            }
        }

  @objc func btn2Pressed(sender: UIButton) {
    
    self.addIndexArray.append(sender.tag)
    
    let hitPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: dataCollectionView)
    if let indexPath = dataCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: hitPoint) {
        print("indexPath--->",indexPath)
        self.arraySelectedFilterIndex.append(getIndexPath)
        self.dataCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [getIndexPath])
        
    }
}
```

**My error:**

I clicked cell btn1 one action btnPressed single cell over load and display the next cell image both images are overlap in collectionview.

Here i attached my issue cell image.

[image]

Here i got cell indexpath and indexpath.row, how can i validate and fix this issue in cell for row. struggling this point.

Kinldy help to fix this issues. Thanks advance.

Comment: are your debugged that this let hitPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: dataCollectionView) gives your cell right indexPath ??, I think some problem in Indexpath

Comment: yes debugged for getting indexPath. how to reload single cell.. help me

Answer (score 0):

You can reload single cell like you are doing in button action

```
self.dataCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [getIndexPath])
```

OR

You can get cell in button action like as below

```
if let cell = self.dataCollectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? DataCell
{
        //Here you can write your view hide show code
        if self.arraySelectedFilterIndex.contains(indexPath) 
        {
            cell.buttonView.isHidden = false
        }
        else
        {
            cell.buttonView.isHidden = true
        }
}
```

Comment: check this condition same issue is there.. help me.